# Convert long date strings in Excel into a sortable date/time format

Tags: excel, date

I have an Excel spreadsheet full of text dates formatted like this:

`Thursday, 23 April 2015, 9:19 AM`

Because they're text, Excel can't sort them chronologically. How do I convert them into a format Excel can work with?

Also, for my future reference, is there a name for this day/date/time format?

Comment: You can use the Text to columns feature. By setting the data type to delimited and using comma as the delimiter it will split the field to 3 columns, the date and time you can then set to be date fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try something like this, if the formats are consistent:-

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("day, ",A1)-4),",","")
```

I don't know what that particular format is called, possibly Long Date, Short Time, at least according to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362btx8f(v=vs.90).aspx).

Although this should sort correctly as a single column since it is a date-time value, it does give a warning message because Excel doesn't know whether to treat it as a number or text, so a better answer would be

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("day, ",A1)-4),",","")+0
```

You can then format it in whatever way you want, so in the UK you would choose the following custom format:-

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
```

With the result

```
23/04/2015 09:19
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tom Sharpe has a good formula there to extract the date, but to make it sortable chronologically, please wrap it in this:

```
=DATEVALUE(toms_formula) + TIMEVALUE(toms_formula)
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe my answer will sort correctly because it is a date-time value, but it does give a warning message. I will edit my answer.

Comment: "+0" that's brilliant! Slightly annoyed it didn't occur to me.

Comment: Thanks, +0 or putting -- in front are useful ways of coercing an expression to be treated as a number.

Answer (score 0):

DATE FORMULA

Transform long date into short =TEXT(I2,"mm-dd-yy")

Week day =TEXT(J2,"Dddd")

Month  =TEXT(DJ2,"Mmmm")

Week ending =DJ2+7-WEEKDAY(DJ2,1)