# Is there a way to convert a Long Date to short date in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an exported file that gives me a list of long dates in format General.
ex: Friday, August 28, 2020

I am trying to convert them into short dates. I've tried using CDate function, but I get a mismatch error. I find this odd because the cell has the exact long date form.

I've tried running a ton of code. Here's the most recent one I tried. It changs the cell format into Long Date. then uses Cdate and gets a mismatch error.

```vb
Sub formatdate()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'


    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F800]dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"

    MsgBox (CDate(Range("J2")))
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your cells contain text, or actual dates?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982652/convert-long-date-strings-in-excel-into-a-sortable-date-time-format

Comment: `selection.value = cdate(mid(selection,instr(selection,",")+1))` then format as you desire.

Comment: @TimWilliams my cells contain "Wednesday, September 2, 2020" as a General Format. If I switch the format, it remains the same "Wednesday, September 2, 2020" so to answer your question, contains text.

Answer (score 1):

As @scottcraner says:

```
Dim v
With Range("J2")
    v = .Value
    v = Mid(v, InStr(v, ",") + 1, 100)
    .Value = DateValue(v)
End With
```